# How to filter out words with at least one unique letter

Tags: python

I have long list of strings called `words`.  All the strings have the same length which is 5. For any i in {0,...,4} we can check to see if the `i`'th letter of a string is also the i'th letter of any other string in the list.  We call a letter at the `i`'th position unique if it is not.

I would like to remove all strings from my list for which there exists any `i` for which the `i`'th letter is unique.

As a very simple example consider: `words = ["apple", "amber", "bpple", "bmber", "appld"]`. The string "appld" should be removed because `d` is unique at the 4th position.

Is there a neat way to do this?

Comment: Make a list whose elements are corresponding to each of the original words. Each element of the list is the count of duplicates of the corresponding letter. When you're done, remove each element of the original list that corresponds to a list that contains `1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `collections.Counter` and the `zip(*...)` transposition idiom:

```
from collections import Counter

# counts for every index
bypos = [*map(Counter, zip(*words))] 

# disallow count 1 for any letter x in its respective position
words = [w for w in words if all(c[x]!=1 for x, c in zip(w, bypos))]
# ['apple', 'amber', 'bpple', 'bmber']
```

Note that is better to rebuild the list in a single iteration than to remove elements repeatedly.

Some docs on the utils used here:

- [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)
- [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)
- [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)
- [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all)
- [unpacking operator `*`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments)

Answer (score 1):

this can be done in O(NlogN) but space inefficient

```
d={}
for j,w in enumerate(words):
    for i,c in enumerate(w):
        if (i,c) in d:
            d[(i,c)].append(j)
        else:
            d[(i,c)]=[j]
for i in reversed(list(set([v[0] for v in d.values() if len(v)==1]))):
    words.pop(i)
print(words)
```